# JavaScript convert STRING "{7: {type: 'line'}}" Into object

Tags: javascript, json

How to convert string

```
"{7: {type: 'line'},8: {type: 'line'}}"
```

into JavasScript OBJECT

```
{7: {type: 'line'},8: {type: 'line'}}
```

Comment: Yes, I saw this posts but it didn't work for me. I'm trying to use google ComboChart and they use a option like this: 

`series: {4: {type: "line"},5: {type: "line"}}`

I build the string  
`4: {type: "line"},5: {type: "line"}`

 from my program but I cannot convert it into a valid 'option' value for googlecombochart:
https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSON.parse

```
JSON.parse(STRING) // convert to object
JSON.stringify(STRING) // convert object to string, that can be used in JSON.parse
```

Don't use numbers as keys, because it bad practice you can't access objects like this:

```
var a = {"8": "value"};
// Invalid syntax
console.log(a.8)
// work
console.log(a["8"], a[8]);

var b = {"eight" : "value"};
// work
console.log(b.eight);
```

Comment: Won't work, the original string is not valid JSON.

Comment: Yes, because it not valid json

Comment: it works, you're right the String was not valid, I changed it by 

`var lineasstr = '{"4":{"type": "line"},"5":{"type": "line"}}';
 JSON.parse(lineasstr);`

and it works with JSON.parse